# Underfloor heating stops working after 5 minutes

Tags: plumbing, heating

I have recently moved into a flat which has underfloor heating. Yesterday I wanted to test it, but it seems that after 5 minutes of working, it doesn't resume again.

The actuators on the manifolds are correctly switched on when the thermostat sends the signal, and initially (from cold) the flow is on (I can feel the specific pipes to be hot), but after 5 minutes it stops working. The seems to be fine.

If I switch it off, let it cool a bit, and then turn it on again it starts working for 5 minutes and then stops again.

Worth mentioning that the heating in the apartment is actually through a Heat Interface Unit, the source of heat being a heating system which supplies heat generated from one energy centre to heat several individual properties and provide hot water to them.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Is it possible since the building heat is not on and/or there is a building thermostat that is preventing it from running?

Comment: Well it works for the first 5 minutes. I have 4 zones in the flat each of them with their own thermostat. My question would be why it works for 5 minutes and then suddenly stops.